# datetime MySQL parsing the date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, parsing

I have a column in my BigQuery Table "date". I need to parse the values of this column in MySql. I currently have the following format for the dates in that column: 
`"2019-10-24T07:00:00"`

And I only need the year - month - date "2019-10-24"

How would I extract the date only in the correct format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL recognize datetimes in this format, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` or `'YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` format.
>
> [...]
>
> The date and time parts can be separated by `T` rather than a space. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'` `'2012-12-31T11:30:45'` are equivalent.

So you can use directly date functions on your input string. To remove the time part of a date, you can use function `date()`:

```
select date('2019-10-24T07:00:00')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29be1ab7e8af1f8a4be2e745f2dcc386)**:

```
select date('2019-10-24T07:00:00') mydate
```

```
| mydate     |
| :--------- |
| 2019-10-24 |
```